# Segmentation Faul(core dumped)

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con mi programa de C, es en la parte de la busqueda. Mi objetivo es ingresar un nuevo articulo y su ID no se debe repetir y el problema creo que esta en la función de buscar o en la de ingresar pero no se como solucionarlo. A veces me tira el error, pero otras veces, directamente no busca el ID, aunque ingrese un que ya exista, no lo detecta.

```
int IngresarNuevoArt(int ID[],int CATEGORIA[],int STOCK[],float PRECIO[],int *cant){
    int valor;
    printf("Ingrese el ID del nuevo articulo\n");
    scanf("%d",&valor);
         if(buscador(ID[*cant],&cant,valor)!=-1){
                printf("Error. El ID ya existe ingrese otro\n");
            } else {
             printf("ingresado\n");
            }
}
int buscador(int vec[],int *cant,int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<*cant;i++){
        if(n==vec[i]){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un *segmentation fault* es una de los tipo usuales de *undefined behavior*, el resultado de escribir un programa que compila pero que hace cosas de forma incorrecta.

**Asumiendo que el fallo está en el código que expones**<sup>1</sup>([revisa como hacer un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), lo que se observa es:

- tanto *IngresarNuevoArt* como *buscador* tienen un parámetro *cant* que es un *int* *. Pero desde *IngresarNuevoArt* haces:

  ```
  if(buscador(ID[*cant],&cant,valor)!=-1){
  ```

  es decir, añades una indirección más al puntero. En todo caso, en ningún sitio asignas un valor a *cant*, por lo que no te sirve de mucho que sea un *int* *. Yo lo cambiaría directamente por *int* para simplificarlo.
- Y también en la misma línea, el elemento que devuelves es *ID[*cant]*. Si  *cant es el tamaño del array, ese elemento ya no es parte del array (si tienes un array de 5 elementos, los índices van de 0 a 4).
- Y de todas formas, *ID[índice]* es un *int* (un elemento del array *ID*) pero lo que acepta *buscador* en el primer parámetro es un *int []* (que en la práctica es como un *int* *). Y *buscador* recorre ese array.

  La versión correcta de esa línea sería:

  ```
  if(buscador(ID,cant,valor)!=-1){
  ```
- *IngresarNuevoArt* tiene que devolver un *int* pero no hay ningún *return*. No creo que esto sea la causa del problema, pero es incorrecto y te dará mensajes de warning. Es importante reducir los mensajes de warning porque:

  - a veces los problemas que detectan son importantes.
  - aunque no sean importantes, si los dejas te acostumbrarás a verlos y cuando aparezcan mensajes importantes no los detectarás.

---

<sup>1</sup> Además, uno de los problemas con los *undefined behavior* es que no está garantizado que donde lo detectas sea donde está el problema. Por ejemplo, un *undefined behavior* puede simplemente modificar datos en zonas que no toque, haciendo que el efecto visible aparezca cuando código perfectamente correcto usa esos valores alterados.